# Cannot install xargo when using rust nightly - "non-string literals in attributes, or string literals in top-level positions, are experimental"

Tags: rust, operating-system

I'm using a specific Rust nightly build for [CS 140E](https://cs140e.sergio.bz/assignments/0-blinky/#phase-4-rusting-away). When I run the commands

```
rustup default nightly-2018-01-09
rustup component add rust-src
cargo install xargo
```

I end up with `libc` failing to build:

> error: non-string literals in attributes, or string literals in top-level positions, are experimental (see issue #34981)
>     --> ~/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/libc-0.2.58/src/macros.rs:78:15

It also mentions

> = help: add #![feature(attr_literals)] to the crate attributes to enable

Which I've done, which brings me to more complex errors that I have less confidence to fix. Is a nightly build failing in this manner expected? I've also tried `rustup default nightly` and `rustup default stable` and they both fail for other reasons.

Comment: Your instructor has forgotten to specify a version of `xargo` that is compatible with that specific version of the compiler. You need to figure out what version of `xargo` works with Rust from over a year ago; presumably a version from around that time. You are likely to encounter this problem with every library you attempt to use. This is normally prevented because `Cargo.lock` records the versions you've selected, but (a) you probably don't have one and (b) Cargo.lock doesn't affect tools installed via `cargo install`.

Comment: xargo is soft deprecated and should only be used for very rare targets. Most of the common targets are nowedays included into the default rust list. Run `rustup target list` to see which targets are available and choose one which suits best for you.